# MDM server not sending push notification to device

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mdm

**devicve being used for test: iPhone 3GS with iOS version 4.2.1**

#### Steps I followed to setup simple mdm server

1. Acquired push notification certificate using Server app on OSX  server. see link below 
   http://www.mountainlionserver.com/enable-push-notifications-in-os-x-mountain-lion-server/
   Once acquired , APNS installed in keychain, exported APSP:XXXXX from keychain as .p12 and converted to pem using **"openssl pkcs12 -in pushCert.p12 -out pushCert.pem."** Removed passphrase using **openssl rsa -in pushCert.pem -out plainkey.pem.** Then in a text editor, replace the encrypted RSA Private Key section in pushCert.pem with the contents of plainkey.pem.
2. Created a self signed root CA using keychaing
3. Created configuration profile using IPCU with mdm payload with Topic " com.apple.mgmt.XServer.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and saved as .mobileconfig
4. Run python MDM server.
5. Installed self signed certificate on iOS device(3gs) created in step 2.
6. Installed .mobileconfig profile on device(iOS 3gs) successfully, on server i see device enrolled successfully and I got following information from device
   PushMagic,Token and UnlockToken I saved this information in a file.
7. Now device is enrolled with server I try to send "DeviceLock" command to device via push notification. But nothing happens. Device is connected to IPCU I see no logs about push notifications there as well which let me assume device is not receiving any push notification.

   #### Here is the code used to send push notification

   - wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('pushcert.pem', False)
     message = APNSNotification()
     message.token(my_DeviceToken)
     message.appendProperty(APNSProperty('mdm', my_PushMagic))
     wrapper.append(message)
     if(wrapper.notify()):
             print "Message sent successfully"
      else:
         print "Failed to send push notification to device"

***Reference*** : http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @Imran Hi Imran .. Have you been able to resolve this issue ? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @sau How far have you reached?Can you tell me the complete process you went through.Are you able to install the profile.If yes then get your device logs.it will be helpful to go through it.

Comment: I am able to install the profile & able to enroll the devices too. But when i send any command to devices then nothing happens on devices. I am also not receiving "idle" status from the devices, hence not receiving acknowledged status too. I am using the same code as given in the above question for sending request to apple. Please help me out.

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue. Can you please tell me what could be issue

Comment: Make sure you have access to gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195